# Aspect for class or subclass annotated with

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to be able to track methods that are anotated with @RequestMapping that are annotated with a certain annotation (for instance @LooseController).

I have two pointcuts: requestMappings() and looseController()

this works well if the method that is annotated with @RequestMapping is in a class that has @LooseController but not if the @LooseController is in a subclass

for instance, when update(id) is called on Controller1 it is not caught by this aspect

---

Update to include more information:

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    private static void requestMapping() {}

    @Pointcut("@within(de.scrum_master.app.LooseController)")
    private static void looseController() {}

//    @Pointcut("@this(de.scrum_master.app.LooseController)")
//    private static void looseController() {}


    @Before("requestMapping() && looseController()")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }

}
```

---

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

//@LooseController
public abstract class PutController {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public void update(String id) {
    }

}
```

---

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface LooseController {
}
```

---

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Component
@LooseController
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class Controller1 extends PutController {
}
```

---

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AspectApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Controller1 controller1;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AspectApplication.class, "--logging.level.root=WARN", "--spring.main.banner-mode=off");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        controller1.update("test");
        context.close();
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>aspects</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspects</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Your question is very unspecific and missing a lot of information necessary to reproduce the problem. All people can do here is specualate. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not just fragments). Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex sorry for the poor quality of the original question, I have updated it to include your classes and the other code that was specific to my situation

Comment: Actually the idea of StackOverflow is that you provide the code and not copy it from the answer. :-/ I was merely guessing what your code might look like. So it seems that I guessed correctly, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I have to speculate:

- It begins with your exact pointcut (which you do not show)
- and goes on with the question whether you use Spring AOP or full AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving).

  - In the former case you do not explain if your target classes are actual Spring beans because Spring AOP can only proxy Spring beans/components.
  - In the latter case you have more options but have to configure your application in a different way.
- You also do not show your own annotation's implementation, especially not if it has the required runtime retention.

My hypothesis for now is that

- you use proxy-based Spring AOP and
- all classes and aspects are `@Component`s or otherwise declared as Spring beans in your configuration.

But in order to show you what happens I will use a stand-alone Java example with AspectJ, not a Spring application. I only put `spring-web.jar` and `sprint-context.jar` on my classpath so as to resolve the Spring annotations.

**Annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LooseController {}
```

**Abstract base class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

public abstract class PutController {
  @RequestMapping("/{id}")
  public void update(String id) {}
}
```

**Subclass + `main` method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Component
@LooseController
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class Controller1 extends PutController {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Controller1().update("foo");
  }
}
```

**The aspect which I guess you might use:**

Please note that your own pointcut `within(@blabla.LooseController)` is syntactically invalid, this is why I changed it to `@within(blabla.LooseController)`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
  private static void requestMapping() {}

  @Pointcut("@within(de.scrum_master.app.LooseController)")
  private static void looseController() {}

  @Before("requestMapping() && looseController()")
  public void myAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log when running `Controller1.main`:**

```
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Controller1.<clinit>)
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Controller1.update(String))
```

Now you see the problem: AspectJ can intercept a few joinpoints for the given pointcut, but neither `call` nor `staticinitialization` are supported by Spring AOP according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators).

So either you need to switch to [AspectJ with LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) or devise another pointcut strategy.

*To be continued, I have to interrupt the answer here for a while because I have an appointment, but will add some more info later.*

---

**Update:** Okay, here is your problem and a solution: `@within(de.scrum_master.app.LooseController)` looks inside classes with the `@LooseController` annotation, but the parent class with the annotated method you are trying to intercept does not have that annotation. Thus, `@within()` is not the right pointcut type for you. What you want to express is that the instance, i.e. the current `target` object upon which the method is called, belongs to an annotated class. Therefore, you need a `@target()` pointcut:

```java
@Pointcut("@target(de.scrum_master.app.LooseController)")
private static void looseController() {}
```

Alternatively you could also use this workaround (a little ugly, but works too):

```java
@Pointcut("target(@de.scrum_master.app.LooseController Object)")
private static void looseController() {}
```

Now the console log says:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.PutController.update(String))
```

This should also work in Spring AOP because `execution()` is a supported pointcut type there.

Comment: Update: added solution

Comment: If i try to use @this i'm getting the following exception
org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'requestMapping() && looseController()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive '@this'

I have updated the original question to include my specific setup

Comment: according to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html @ this is not supported by spring aop

"The full AspectJ pointcut language supports additional pointcut designators that are not supported in Spring. These are: [...], @this [...]. Use of these pointcut designators in pointcut expressions interpreted by Spring AOP will result in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown."

Comment: This was really close, even though 'this' is not supported, 'target' is, by replacing 'this' with 'target' in looseController i get the expected behavior

Comment: Of course, I forgot about this Spring limitation. I tried with full AspectJ. And  `@this()` or `this()` would not have worked in all cases anyway. `@target()` or `target()` are better anyway. I have updated the answer.